# Enumerating dis-connected regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory

### Question

How can I enumerate all dis-connected *k*-regular graphs on *n* vertices?

### What I tried

Meringer's [GENREG](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/reggraphs.html) code enumerates *connected* *k*-regular graphs. I looked over his *C* code but did not see an easy way to include dis-connected graphs.

## Edit #1

*dis-connected* here means not connected. For example, one solution for the graph with *6* vertices and degree *2* is two triangles. The adjacency list for  that would be:

1: 2,3

2: 1,3

3: 1,2

4: 5,6

5: 4,6

6: 4,5

Comment: What is a "dis-connected" graph? Is it just "not connected"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to generate this using the **geng** utility from the [nauty](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/) program. The commands and output are below. The first solution is a "circle of nodes" and the second is "two triangles".

```
$ nauty26r11/geng.exe 6 -d2D2 > n6d2.g6
>A nauty26r11/geng -d2D2 n=6 e=6
>Z 2 graphs generated in 0.00 sec

$ cat n6d2.g6
EEh_
EQhO

$ nauty26r11/showg.exe ./n6d2.g6

Graph 1, order 6.
  0 : 3 4;
  1 : 3 5;
  2 : 4 5;
  3 : 0 1;
  4 : 0 2;
  5 : 1 2;

Graph 2, order 6.
  0 : 2 4;
  1 : 3 5;
  2 : 0 4;
  3 : 1 5;
  4 : 0 2;
  5 : 1 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure precisely what your definition of *dis-connected* is, but since edgeless graphs are only $k$-regular for $k=0$ it must either be

1. All graphs which are not connected, or
2. All graphs.

Either way, [Riddell's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiddellsFormula.html) is the name given to the transform which maps the generating function for connected graphs having suitable property $P$ to all graphs which have property $P$. For unlabelled graphs it's the Euler transform $$1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n x^n  = \prod_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1-x^i)^{a_i}}$$
where $a_i$ is the number of connected graphs with $i$ vertices and property $P$, and $b_i$ is the number of all graphs with $i$ vertices and property $P$.

An alternative way of thinking of it, which is probably more useful computationally, is that the graphs on $n$ vertices can be enumerated by considering the partitions of $n$ into integers $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_k$ and then for each such partition taking the Cartesian product $C_{\lambda_1} \times C_{\lambda_2} \times \cdots \times C_{\lambda_k}$ where $C_i$ is the set of connected graphs with $i$ vertices and property $P$. (NB Specifically you want the Cartesian product to give you a multiset, because the connected components are not necessarily distinct).